# Nlog ConnectionAborted and ConnectionReset

Tags: c#, nlog

I have some project that uses Nlog for logging exceptions. It worked normally about 2 years. Recently, I've got the following messages:

```
 NLog.NLogRuntimeException: Exception occurred in NLog ---> System.IO.IOException: Error: ConnectionAborted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Write>b__0(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Internal.SingleCallContinuation.Function(Exception exception)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Write>b__9(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ChunkedSend>b__1a(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.SocketOperationCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.ProcessNextQueuedItem()
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.DoSend(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length, AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.NetworkSender.Send(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length, AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ChunkedSend>b__1a(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.ChunkedSend(NetworkSender sender, Byte[] buffer, AsyncContinuation continuation)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(TargetWithFilterChain targetListHead, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory)
   at NLog.Logger.WriteToTargets(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Logger.Log(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Internal.SingleCallContinuation.Function(Exception exception)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Write>b__9(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ChunkedSend>b__1a(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.SocketOperationCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.ProcessNextQueuedItem()
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.TcpNetworkSender.DoSend(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length, AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
   at NLog.Internal.NetworkSenders.NetworkSender.Send(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length, AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ChunkedSend>b__1a(Exception ex)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.ChunkedSend(NetworkSender sender, Byte[] buffer, AsyncContinuation continuation)
   at NLog.Targets.NetworkTarget.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(TargetWithFilterChain targetListHead, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory)
   at NLog.Logger.WriteToTargets(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Logger.Log(LogEventInfo logEvent)
```

I've got 2 types of errors: *ConnectionReset* and *ConnectionAborted*. I can not find the cause of errors. What do these errors mean?

Comment: Where are you writing your logs to? Does it go over the network? Seems your app is not able to connect to a remote host over TCP. Basically looks like a remote server / networking issue, due to which the remote host is not available at the address your app was using.

Comment: In addition to what was said above, you could enable [internal logging](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting), It may show you more (which of I'm not completely sure).